# Episerver: hide a content type from showing up in the list of available blocks for main content area?

Tags: episerver

In Episerver in the main content area if you click on "create a new block" you are shown a list of blocks that can be added into this main content area.

We have created a custom block which I would like to hide from this list so that editors cannot see it.

Custom Block:

```
namespace Test.Site.Models.Forms
{
    [SiteImageUrl]
    [ContentType(GUID = "c9f294a0-6620-47c3-98fd-123f0fd8db8c")]
    public class CalculatorFormBlock : BaseTestCustomFormContainerBlock<GatedContentSuccessMessageBlock>
    {

    }
}
```

Is there a default method in Episerver to do this?

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the solution. Feel free to add this as an answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AvailableInEditMode` property (set it to false) of `ContentType` attribute to completely hide it from editing (also available as a checkbox in admin UI).

More details in [episerver documentation](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/Content/Attributes/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [allowed types attribute](https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Ben-McKernan/Dates/2015/2/the-new-and-improved-allowed-types/) on the main content area to only allow the blocks you want. It also works with interfaces.